# I behave and am armed

Tags: wordplay, anagram, letters

> Starting with `I behave and am armed`, do all the following in the correct order to reveal a famous American history quote.
>
> 1. Remove one word
> 2. Remove two letters from a word
> 3. Replace one word with its anagram
> 4. Remove one letter from another word

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is

> I have a dream!

I behave and am armed
Remove 1 word

> I behave am armed

Remove 2 letters from a word

> I **have** am armed

Replace one word with its anagram

> I have am **dream**

Remove one letter from another word

> I have **a** dream