# Yes, leaves turn different tones

Tags: word, wordplay, anagram, letters

A throw back to my very [first puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49271/i-behave-and-am-armed) here on Puzzling SE, you have to  complete the steps listed for each bolded phrase to reveal a secret quote!

**1. Yes, leaves turn different tones.**

> 1. Find the antonym of one word.
> 2. Remove a word.
> 3. Remove a letter.
> 4. Find the anagram of one word.
> 5. Add a prefix and a suffix to one word.
> 6. Remove a comma and rearrange the words.

**2. Could one be fine?**

> 1. Remove a word.
> 2. Remove a letter.
> 3. Change a letter.
> 4. Rearrange the words.
> 5. Find the anagram of one word.

Comment: Nice puzzle and grats on 4k rep :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1:

> Start at: *Yes, leaves turn different tones.*
> Step 1: *No, leaves turn different tones.*
> Step 2: *No, leaves turn tones.*
> Step 3: *No, leave turn tones.*
> Step 4: *No, leave turn stone.*
> Step 5: *No, leave unturned stone.*
> Step 6: *Leave no stone unturned.*

Credit goes to Tan for the answer for 2:

> On cloud nine.

Comment: Yup, that is the correct answer for #1.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Yup added explanation and still trying to figure out #2 haha

Comment: Good explanation!

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Welp, looks like our edits crossed in the post :-)

Comment: Hahaha, at least it is fixed now ^-^

Comment: So I don't have to ask for an edit about the formatting again, how do you do that?

Comment: You have to add <br> at the end of the line you would like to separate :D

Comment: Had an idea for #2 but doesn't work for steps 3-5 --> rot13 (bar ol bar?)

Answer (score 11):

Einb answered the first. The second is

> 1. Could one fine
>  2. Could on fine
>  3. Could on nine
>  4. On could nine
>  5. On cloud nine.

Comment: That is correct great job!

Comment: Oh, Welcome to puzzling SE, I hope you stay :D